# How to validate entry in Craft 3

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

An entry could be validated by the following code in craft 2:

```
craft()->content->validateContent($entry);
```

How could be the same done in Craft 3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every model has a `validate()` function

```php
// set the scenario to live
$entry->setScenario(Element::SCENARIO_LIVE);

// validate the model
$entry->validate();

// get the errors,
$errors = $entry->getErrors();
```

Comment: I am trying to get errors on required fields when an entry is disabled. `$errors = $entry->getErrors()` returns an empty array in this case.

Comment: That's because of the default behavior and scenario. Those fields are not required when the entry is disabled. You'll need to change the Scenario first or enable it otherwise `getErrors()` won't return errors since there are none

Comment: I added setting the scenario before validation, which should now give you errors for your required fields.